# AndroidCircularSeekBar Not Displaying Correctly in Fragment after Fragment Replace

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm using an Activity with two Fragments. Fragment #1 is a login screen. Once the user logs in the activity changes fragments via fragment transactions. The second Fragment #2 contains the circularSeekBar. Both fragments are using xml layouts. The activity has a xml layout with a FrameLayout (R.id.fragmentContainer).  The problem is the circularSeekBar is not updating its display and not drawing the circle. (It only shows the little knob image) It does works if I display the circularSeekBar fragment first with out login. The problem only occurs if it is shown second (replaced). I've tried using circularSeekBar.invalidate() but does not help. Not sure where to call it or what else to try. I've tried using invalidate() in the Fragment's onResume() & void onStart() no luck. I'm getting reference to the circularSeekBar in onCreateView. (Normal stuff). Another thing I noticed is it will start to work if I try to touch it. (The knob. So it can be refreshed some how)

Here is where I get reference to it in onCreateView(...)

```
circularSeekBar = (CircularSeekBar)v.findViewById(R.id.circularSeekBar_circular_seek_bar);

        circularSeekBar.setSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekChangeListener() 
        {
              @Override
              public void onProgressChange(CircularSeekBar view, int newProgress) 
              {
                        float value = translateValueFromSourceIntervalToDestinationInterval(
                                (float)newProgress,
                                (float)0.0,
                                (float)100.0,
                                (float)65.0,
                                (float)85.0
                        );

                        setpointValue.setText(""+(int)value);
                        updateLeafImage((int)value);
                  }
        });

        circularSeekBar.setProgress(50);
        circularSeekBar.invalidate();
```

Here is where I replace it in the Activity:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

                Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

                if(fragment != null)
                {
                    ((LoginFragment) fragment).setDelegate(null);
                }

                Fragment cirFragment = new cirFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,cirFragment);

                // Commit the transaction
                transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution:

In the protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
they were get the width and height via getWidth() and getHeight().

I changed this to:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        width = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
```

This corrected the problem.